# how to apply password on the zip file or on the csv in nodejs or javascript

Tags: passwords, zip

```
var csvString = ['rest','test','age'];
var fileName_CSV = "Report_1.csv"; 
var fileName_ZIP = "Report_1.zip";

var blob = new Blob(dd,{type: application/zip"});
var zip = new JSZip();
zip.file(fileName_CSV,csvString),{type:"blob"};
var content = zip.generate({type:"blob"});

saveAs(content,fileName_ZIP);
```

I have the json data i have converted it to fit in csv format so i created the csv file with the data then saves it in memory and now zipped the csv file and now i want to apply password on it .. so when we open the zip and try to open the csv it should ask for the user defined password.. and either i want to use java script or nodejs for it... please help

Answer (score 0):

The mini-zip-asm package supports creating zip archives with passwords.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/minizip-asm.js

**From the docs:**

> **npm install minizip-asm.js**

**Example Usage:**

```
var Minizip = require('minizip-asm.js');
var fs = require("fs");
var csvString = new Buffer("Abc~~~");

var mz = new Minizip(); 
mz.append("Report_1.csv", csvString, {password: "insert-password"}); 
fs.writeFileSync("Report_1.zip", new Buffer(mz.zip()));
```